# Unable to open textfile using IE

Tags: internet-explorer

For our application, we log in notepad. We provided web URL to user to view log. We save file on file system. Our users are not able to open some of the log file. Can anyone help me here? we store text/xml inside the .txt file. we are getting following error while trying to see a log file

```
The XML page cannot be displayed 
Cannot view XML input using style sheet. Please correct the error and then click 
the Refresh button, or try again later. 

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Invalid at the top level of the document. Error processing resource
```

If someone can help me, i can send .txt files to them. This text file open successfully in Chrome and firefox

"SAVE THIS AS .txt AND TRY TO OPEN WITH IE"

2010-10-14 08:38:49,452 [1] DEBUG -

UserHostAddress 198.96.178.33 
UserHostName 198.96.178.33 
UserAgent Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.0.1
10/14/2010 8:38:49 AM 
Request factivafacpassword1230IBM1100Name10/14/2010 08:38:45

2010-10-14 08:38:51,983 [1] DEBUG -

Response 10/14/2010 8:38:51 AM 
 13201116695SANIBM Canada Credit Services Company,CanadaManitoba Securities Commission Enforcement Orders & Exceptions3201158540SANInternational Business Machines Corporation,United StatesSEC - Litigation Releases210/14/2010 8:38:51 AM
2010-10-14 08:39:30,452 [7] DEBUG -

UserHostAddress 198.96.178.33 
UserHostName 198.96.178.33 
UserAgent Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.0.1
10/14/2010 8:39:30 AM 
Request factivafacpassword1230CFX Holdings1100Name10/14/2010 08:39:30

2010-10-14 08:39:30,967 [7] DEBUG -

Response 10/14/2010 8:39:30 AM 
 1010/14/2010 8:39:30 AM

Comment: Please show some code, e.g. an example of the link

Comment: Here is content of my file. Just save it as .txt and try to open it with IE

Comment: i am unable to paste file as it is bigger than limit in comment. give me your email id and i will send you as an attachment

Comment: you can copy and paste some part of it in the question itself right?

Comment: OK. I modified and copy/paste sample into my question itself

Answer (score 2):

IE is interpreting the file as an xml document and trying to open it. But the file does not seem to be in correct xml format. hence you are getting the error.

Comment: but it works fine with chrome & firefox. Some of file i am able to open with IE too. But some fails. If you can give me your email, i can send you some sample

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are being bitten by type sniffing.

When IE receives a resource of type `text/plain` (as will normally be served for `.txt`), it doesn't trust that type.

(This is because web servers default to passing the type `text/plain` when they don't know what type a resource is, instead of simply omitting the `Content-Type` header. This is the Wrong Thing, but most web servers do it.)

Instead, IE looks at the beginning of the file to see if there's anything in there it recognises. If it sees something like `<?xml` that looks like XML, it'll decide that the entire file is `text/xml`, and not `text/plain` like the server said it was. This is of course also the Wrong Thing, and has caused some serious security problems in the past, but MS can't disable it in IE now without breaking a load of existing poorly-administered sites.

Exactly when, how, and what types IE sniffs for is a [complicated story](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775147%28VS.85%29.aspx). In IE8+, you can avoid this unpleasantness by returning your `text/plain` resources with the extra header:

```
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
```

As [detailed on the IEBlog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/07/02/ie8-security-part-v-comprehensive-protection.aspx).

For earlier versions of IE it is difficult to stop random arbitrary text in a `text/plain` resource throwing off the sniffer. A simple but ugly solution if you need to support these IE versions is to fill the first 256 bytes of the file with content-free-filler (eg. 256 spaces). The sniffer only looks at this part of the file.

Comment: Does it mean that when i try to put XML in by log file, i should have 256 space before it?

Comment: If you need to support IE<8 and you don't fancy manually filtering out content that looks like other file types then yes, this is what you'd have to do. Messy, I know. Sorry.